# CSS3-only carousel not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations

This is the page (in the section with the headline: EXPERIENCE A PLACE—BEFORE YOU GET THERE over to the right, in FF you'll only see a pic of a piece of salmon, if it works you'll also see meat in red sauce and ceviche).

http://www.celebritycruises.com/htmlpage/html-page-test

I use the CSS3 animate property to change the background image of one of the tiles. Works in Chrome, Safari, IE 10+, but it's not working in FF (with or without -moz-)

Any ideas?

```
main #onboard section:nth-child(3) section:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation:pulse 5s infinite;
    background:url(/media/en_US/images/cel_deployment/Global_Culinary/800x400/food01_800x400.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    height:55%;
}
@keyframes pulse {
33% {
    background:url(/media/en_US/images/cel_deployment/Global_Culinary/800x400/food02_800x400.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
66% {
    background:url(/media/en_US/images/cel_deployment/Global_Culinary/800x400/food03_800x400.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
99% {
    background:url(/media/en_US/images/cel_deployment/Global_Culinary/800x400/food01_800x400.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be the answer. According to this, the background-image property is not supposed to be animatable. Which doesn't mean that it can't be animated, since Chrome, Safari, and IE all do.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-css3-background-20140909/#background-image